# How to insert variable data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, variables, syntax

I need help to figure out why this is not working. I apparently don't understand the syntax for interting variables in the database. Without the variable in the array, this database insertion is functioning so the problem does not come from there. I also echo the variable further up in the file so the variable exists and functions.

```
if(isset($_POST['ticket_priority']))
{
// Get the nonce value for validation
$nonce = $_POST['ticket_nonce'];
// If the nonce does not verify, do NOT process the form.
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'MyNonceAction')) {
     // If this spits out an error, that means the nonce failed
     echo 'Security error. Do not process the form.';
     return;
}
insert_row();
}
$donneesPost = get_post();
echo $donneesPost->ID; //this works


function insert_row()
{
global $wpdb, $donneesPost;

$tablename = 'pp_candidates';
$data = array( 
'candidate_email' => 'email@email.com', //just to see that without a variable it functions
'project_ID' => $donneesPost->ID,
    'candidate_approved' => '1' 
 );

var_dump($data);
$formats = array( 
  //  '%d', // ticket_id should be an integer
  //  '%s', // ticket_user_id should be an integer
  //  '%d', // ticket_description should be a string
  //  '%s' // ticket_user_id should be an integer
); 

$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->insert($tablename, $data, $formats);
}

function display_form(){
echo '
<form action="" method="post">';
// Add a nonce field
wp_nonce_field('MyNonceAction', 'ticket_nonce');
echo '
<input type="submit" name="ticket_priority" value = "Postuler pour ce projet" id="insertcandidatebutton">
</form> 
';
}
display_form();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Erreur de la base de données WordPress : [Column 'project_ID' cannot
>   be null] INSERT INTO `pp_candidates` (`candidate_email`, `project_ID`,
>   `candidate_approved`) VALUES ('emqil@email.com', NULL, '1')

Here is the solution proposed by grumpy

```
// This is what it was like in the original post
    insert_row();
    }
    $donneesPost = get_post();

// This is what I changed to get it to work
    $donneesPost = get_post();
    insert_row();
    }
```

Comment: `$donneesPost->ID` is `null`, which the table does not allow. Where does `$donneesPost` come from? To be clear, your problem is not because you are using a variable, it's because the variable you are using doesn't exist.

Comment: You probably just need to move `$donneesPost = get_post();` right above where you call `insert_row();`. In fact, you should just pass `$donneesPost` to the function `insert_row(get_post());`

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica I had never thought about putting above insert_row(). That did the trick. Thanks. Since you commented and did not answer, I don't know how to accept your solution. So I changed
    $donneesPost = get_post();
    insert_row();
    }
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If `$donnesPost` does not have a key named `ID`, the statement `$donnesPost->ID` will silently return `NULL`, and this is what's happening here.

The same thing will happen, believe it or not, if `$donnesPost` isn't defined at all:  PHP will spit a "warning" message to the log-file *and keep going!!*  It looks to me like, at the point where `update_post()` is being called, the variable is not *yet* defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This is the solution suggested by Grumpy says Reinstate Monica which functions

```
// This is what it was like in the original post
    insert_row();
    }
    $donneesPost = get_post();

// This is what I changed to get it to work
    $donneesPost = get_post();
    insert_row();
    }
```